# Screenshot of entire element with element which is scrollable

Tags: testcafe

I want to perform a visual regression test on an element which is inside a div element with `overflow:auto`. This means it is scrollable and does usually not fit the screen. If an element screenshot is taken, there is no option like `fullPage: true` for `takeElementScreenshot()` in testcafe. Also if I take a fullpage screenshot the `#sidebar-quicklinks` is cropped as well. A simple example would be:

```
test.page("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts")(
  "2 Check Studienabschluss FE",
  async (t) => {
    await t.takeScreenshot({
      path: "pre_post/2.png",
      fullPage: true,
    });

    await t.takeElementScreenshot("#sidebar-quicklinks", "pre_post/3.png", {
      includeMargins: true,
    });
  }
);
```

How can I take a full screenshot of teh element `#sidebar-quicklinks` in testcafe? I was thinking about changing the resoltion of the window with `resizeWindow()` but this might break video capture if I am not mistaken.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `takeElementScreenshot` method cannot capture the full element if it extends beyond the viewport. However, you can capture a full-page screenshot without cropping `#sidebar-quicklinks`. To achieve this, you need to modify the styles of `.sidebar-container` and `#sidebar-quicklinks` via [ClientFunction](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/client-functions), and then take a full-page screenshot:

```
import {ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const changeStyles = ClientFunction(() => {
  document.querySelector('#sidebar-quicklinks').setAttribute('style','overflow: unset');
  document.querySelector('.sidebar-container').setAttribute('style','max-height: unset');
})

test.page("[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts")(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts%22)()
  "2 Check Studienabschluss FE",
  async (t) => {
    await t.takeScreenshot({
      path: "pre_post/2.png",
      fullPage: true,
    });
  }
);
```